# Serial communication in Java

Tags: java, serial-port

I have problem with Serialio library for using serial port, it works on XP but it doesn't work on Windows 7 on my computer, but what is strange works on Windows 7 on friend computer. I got message, not error, Platform not supported. Does anybody have any experience with this ?

Comment: [Supported Platforms](http://serialio.com/products/serialport/SerialPortPlatforms.php). From that, it appears that it should work...have any more details about your OS? Perhaps it has something to do with your Java environment?

Answer (score 1):

check settings of serial I/O? I am not familiar with serialIO library but I know some serial Win32 APIs. 
I read some sample code like this:

```
GetCommState(hport, &mDCB);
/* do something to change settings */
SetCommState(hport, &mDCB);
```

In some situation, this would cause unexpected problem.
Retrieved variables are not all modified by your program and those un-modified part might change the result of execution.

Answer (score 0):

Just trying to understand, you have both XP and Win7 on your computer (via dual boot i assume?)

Perhaps related to UAC being turned on? Maybe your friends machines have that turned off, and its turned on on your machine. Or perhaps you can try running your app with administrator privileges. Other than that, you start looking at patch levels between with windows7 machines, as well as making sure your serial port is actually configured properly in windows7.